# How to set TimePicker show with format 24h

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a TimePicker in layout and I want it to show time with format 24h.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`TimePicker` is a view for selecting the time of day, in either 24 hour or AM/PM mode.
You can use [`setIs24HourView(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29) method with [TimePicker.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29)

Answer (score 46):

Setting `TimePicker` by default to 24 hour mode is not always a good idea since many countrys have diffrent convention. For this case use `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())`.

Your final code migth look like `picker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this));`.

Further details see:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

Comment: There are several DateFormat classes, to use the right one: timePicker.setIs24HourView(android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context));

Answer (score 24):

If you want the TimePicker to be correctly initialized with the current time in 24h format use the following:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Otherwise, due to Android bug, the picker will start with an incorrect hour (2 instead of 14 etc).

Comment: How can you set the hour day for example 5PM?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to retrieve the TimePicker instance from the view after inflating it, then you can modify the widget.

Ids are arbitrary:

```
View v=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);
TimePicker timePicker=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_timePicker);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

xml

```
<TimePicker
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker" />
```

java

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);    
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, it displays time in the AM/PM format. If you want to change time in the 24 hour format, then you can use the setIs24HourView() method. 
See this link: http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/timepicker-view-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I need the same just for an application to set the duration spend for doing a task. I found that I just need to extend the TimePickerDialog class and pass True in the last constructor parameter boolean is24HourView.

```
public class DurationPickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

public DurationPickerDialog(Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute){
    super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, true);
}
```

Then you only need to create this as

```
TimePickerDialog durationPicker =  new DurationPickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute);
durationPicker.setTitle("Duration:");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need call and send **true** to **setIs24HourView** function.

```
TimePicker tpHourMin = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
tpHourMin.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people have already mentioned just set the parameter to true or false.

timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

You can find a complete example with source code to download from here
http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-timepicker-example/

Answer (score 0):

Or you let the user **decide for himself** which format he want to use.

In your MainActivty:

```
DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");


   @Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            TextView outputText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            outputText.setText(hourOfDay + " : "+ minute);
}
```

And in a new Java Class (TimePickerFragment):

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);



    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

}}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and answer to the question, not a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**For Time picker Dialog**

Timepicker dialog provides by android to select the time.

Java provides default functionality by passing is24HourView == true in TimePickerDialog constructor.

```
public TimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute,boolean is24HourView) {
        this(context, 0, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }
```

Pass true for 24 hours or pass false to set time picker dialog in AM-PM format.

**for ex: (Kotlin)**

```
 private fun showTimePicker() {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dialog = TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
            Log.e("Time :","$hourOfDay:$minute")
        }, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true) //here pass true for 24hrs view else false for AM-PM(12hrs view)
        dialog.show()
    }
```