# set time picker 24hour dynamically

Tags: android

in my android app, i have an time picker like this:

```
mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Settings.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
         @Override
         public void onTimeSet(TimePicker tpReminderTime, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
           // DO SOMETHING
         }
     }
}, hour, minute, true);
mTimePicker.setTitle(getString(R.string.TpDialogTitel));
mTimePicker.show();
```

I have to modify this line:

```
}, hour, minute, true);
```

true = show 24 hours format

How can i change the format, if the user comes from a country, where the 24h hour format is not typical.

i thought, i can try to get the device language for that, to analyze, which format i have to use. but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453075/how-to-set-timepicker-show-with-format-24h

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(false);
```

Then, detect the language on the device with:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```