# Can i use 24hours without TimePicker in xml?

Tags: android

Now, can show in 12 hours format but i don't know how to get 24 hours. 
But i don't use the timepicker function in android

Can you suggest me? Thanks.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        inputTimePic.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        tpd.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set TimePicker show with format 24h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453075/how-to-set-timepicker-show-with-format-24h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change last parameter of `TimePickerDialog()` to true.
update your code like this:

```
     TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
         @Override
          public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                inputTimePic.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, true); //true means 24 hour and false means 12 hour
 tpd.show();
```

For adding extra 0 before hour and minute:

```
 if(selectedHour <= 9 && selectedMinute <= 9){
                            tvTime.setText("0"+selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                        }else if(selectedHour <= 9){
                            tvTime.setText("0"+selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }else if(selectedMinute <= 9){
                            tvTime.setText(""+selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                        }else {
                            tvTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }
```

Comment: @swett.bp if your issue is solved then you should mark correct green sign so others can get accurate answer from this question.

Comment: I have more question. How can i get time in text like 09 not only 9. Thanks you.

Comment: just print 0 in the text view before you set 9

Comment: Don't have condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109792/discussion-between-parsania-hardik-and-swett-bp).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109808/discussion-between-parsania-hardik-and-swett-bp).

Answer (score 0):

TimePickerDialog has below format

```
TimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute,
            boolean is24HourView)
```

To get data in 24 hour format, you can send true flag for `is24HourView`